# Why can't Typescript infer the argument types of this function?

Tags: types, typescript

Say we have this type declaration:

```
declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

If we define a method which states this to be this type, why can't typescript deduce the types of the arguments?

```
const fetchJson: MethodDecorator = (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
    ...
}
```

Typescripts infer the arguments as having the `any` type. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contextual typing of function expressions does not occur when the contextual type's signature is generic. This is because it would cause the type parameter type to "leak out", which is a big no-no -- you should never be able to see an unspecified type parameter `T` *outside* the declaration in which it was declared.

You could fix this by moving the type parameter to the *type* instead of being on the *signature*:

```
type SomeMethodDecorator<T> = (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;

let x: SomeMethodDecorator<string> = (a, b, c) => {
    // a: Object, etc.
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of this "leaking out" of type parameters if contextual typing of generic signatures worked? I'm sure it all makes sense, I'm just having problem getting my head around it.